# Geodesic triangle strip algorithm

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, geometry

I think somewhere in the literature there is an algorithm that, given 2 points on a triangle mesh, finds the triangle strip through which the geodesic passes, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://youtu.be/DbNEsryLULE

Comment: Not quite, that apper computes a geodesic through edge flips. I am looking for the set of triangles in teh original mesh through which the geodesic passes.

Comment: I believe you can compute the geodesic using the above and then check through which triangles it passes in the original mesh.

Comment: That would be a lot of computations : p especially when you take into account that their method assumes you already have a triangle strip connecting the endpoints.